# ArangoDB with custom JS

Tags: node.js, arangodb

Hello is there any way to use JS environment built in ArangoDB to execute custom JS? I'd like to set up path to my JS files which would be executed instead of foxx application files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via GitHub: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1723#issuecomment-183289699

> You are correct that modules are cached independently of the routing
>   cache. Clearing the module cache (or preventing a module from being
>   cached) is currently not supported.
>
> The actions mechanism is really only intended as an internal API and
>   only supported for backwards compatibility with early ArangoDB
>   versions and some edge cases.
>
> As you may have noticed while digging through the ArangoDB source
>   code, Foxx provides a per-service module cache which is cleared
>   whenever a Foxx service is reloaded. I would strongly encourage you to
>   see whether Foxx fits your use case before continuing to dig into the
>   actions mechanism.
>
> It's actually possible to create a Foxx service with just two files (a
>   manifest and a controller file) and without using repositories or
>   models (you can just use the same APIs available in actions).
>
> You just need a controller file like this (e.g. `ctrl.js`):
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
> const Foxx = require('org/arangodb/foxx');
> const ctrl = new Foxx.Controller(applicationContext);
> ctrl.get('/', function (req, res) {
>   res.send('Hello World');
> });
> ```
>
> with a `manifest.json` like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "my-foxx",
>   "version": "0.0.0",
>   "controllers": "ctrl.js",
>   "defaultDocument": "",
>   "engines": {"arangodb": "^2.8.0"}
> }
> ```
>
> You can then mount the service (upload a zip bundle) at a path like
>   `/db` and access it:
>
> ```
> curl http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/db
> ```
>
> The upcoming 3.0 release will remove a lot of the existing conceptual
>   overhead of Foxx which will hopefully make it even easier to get
>   started with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with [User Actions](https://docs.arangodb.com/ArangoActions/index.html). Foxx was created as a more comfortable alternative and is likely a better choice for non-trivial applications. The documentation can be intimidating but Foxx services can actually be very lightweight and simple (see my other answer). If you really don't want to use Foxx for this, here's how to do it manually:

First create a virtual module in the `_modules` system collection:

```
var db = require('org/arangodb').db;
db._modules.save({
  path: '/db:/ownTest',
  content: `
    exports.do = function (req, res, options, next) {
      res.body = 'test';
      res.responseCode = 200;
      res.contentType = 'text/plain';
    };
  `
});
```

Then create a route that uses it:

```
db._routing.save({
  url: '/ourtest', 
  action: {
    controller: 'db://ownTest'
  }
});
```

Finally, tell ArangoDB to update its routing cache so it notices the new route:

```
require('internal').reloadRouting();
```

If you [install your JavaScript module](https://docs.arangodb.com/ModuleJavaScript/index.html) to the `js/common/` or the `js/server/` directory you can use the module name (e.g. `myOnDiskModule`) instead of the virtual module name `"db://owntest"` in the `controller`.

For smaller modules you can just define the function inline using `callback` instead of `controller`:

```
db._routing.save({ 
  url: '/hello/echo',
  action: { 
    callback: `
      function (req, res) {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.body = require('js-yaml').safeDump({
          Hello: 'World',
          are: 'you here?'
        });
      }
    `
  } 
});
```

Remember to always update the routing cache after changes to the routing collection:

```
require('internal').reloadRouting();
```

Note: the `callback` implementation in 2.8 has a bug that will be fixed in 2.8.3. If you want to apply the fix manually, it's in [commit b714dc5](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/b714dc563a463191ce1167b3fb0707dba4cf3010).

Comment: I was able to run custom script from disk which logged a string to console, but when I changed the script it didn't do anything. It didn't do new stuff but also wasn't logging anymore. Is there some cache or something that needs to be refreshed? I tried to run require('internal').reloadRouting(); in JS Shell, but it didn't help. After database process restart, new code gets applied. Is there any way to avoid restarting database?

Comment: Here for FOXX offers development mode. You have to do this yourselves by using `require("internal").load("/some/test/.js")`

Comment: dothebart, the command results in `TypeError: require(...).load is not a function`

Comment: How would I access database other than _system from such module?

Comment: you can place `_db/[databasename]/...` in the URL or run `require("internal")._useDatabase()` before the require. However, the recommended way of doing this is to use FOXX.

Comment: did the answers fulfill your needs? if yes, can you mark the answer as accepted? If not, whats missing?

Comment: I got a better suggestion on github, to use foxx but with minimum boilerplate.

Comment: @MáriusRak I've posted the answer you preferred from our GitHub discussion. Could you mark it as accepted so we can close this, or do you want me to elaborate?